# Can i make operating system using FreeBSD kernel? And build same alternative as Chromium-OS only HTML5

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, freebsd, chromium

I was thinking if Chromium-OS is completely a web browser based. Then what is the reason not use FreeBSD kernel and make same HTML5 based OS? Which can at-least have an evaluation of Chromium-OS, but in FreeBSD architecture.

Will it be possible to do such? Or BSD is not friendlier then Linux kernel's? After all its a common sense of concept introduced clearly by Chromium-OS.

Thanks in advanced.

**Follow up:** Vision & Mission:: "Life without walls, who need Windows?"
How do i build my micro operating system, with linux kernel, its all about me?

Step 1: Collect materials

a) some existing and working images so that we can wrap the file-system and directory tree
http://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/  (they are built in images, so inside it has all the directory skeleton)

b) make a directory skeleton, where you can put all those such as following by copy and paste with original materials form above (/tmp/myOS/):

```
/
/boot <-- here goes the grub and lilo and boot loader
/tmp
/lib  <-- here goes the kernel
/root
/etc etc
```

Step 2: Build kernel

```
1) Download linux kernel: www.kernel.org

2) Setup the kernel and build it
make menuconfig
save it as .config
apply make or make -j3

3) install processor emulator
yum -y install qemu nasm

4) run it
qemu -m 124M -kernel /tmp/myKernel/../zImage
```

Step 3: Attach kernel & Directory skeleton

```
1) compiled/builded kernel was created copy that and paste it to /tmp/myOS/lib/
2) make sure the directory and grub/lilo/bootloaders are fine tunned
3) keep on testing..., should work hoping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

One of the most prominent Linux distributions to date, Debian, also does this. See here: http://www.debian.org/ports/kfreebsd-i386/

So, if it runs Debian, it will also run your web OS.

Comment: Thanks, do you also know such links which guides step by step such as cheat sheet to build own os? ex: http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~sandhya/csc256/assignments/qemu_linux.html

Comment: Frankly, OS kernel is the big job, which is already open source requires some steps to follow, and it will allow anyone who understand a little to build his first "hello world" os. I am after that research actually, just to learn how exciting these are.

Comment: I have some updates above. Am i in correct direction? Thanks!